# Using imported font with XeLaTeX - several latin letters for one font symbol

Tags: xetex, symbols

I am importing a custom font that I made into my document, and compiling it using XeLaTeX. Let's call the font "MyFont" for sake of argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\myfont="MyFont" at 12pt
\begin{document}

{\myfont Hello, world!}

\end{document}
```

So the result is the character associated with "H" is displayed first, then the character associated with "e", etc. Since this specific font is actually an approximation of an ancient runic script, the displayed characters have some analogies to sounds in English, but not always of a single letter. For instance, one letter sounds something like the English amalgamation "ngh", and some just like "a".

As such, I would like to be able to type `{\myfont a{ngh}}` and have only two symbols appear. I'm using curly brackets around the "ngh" to show that that is one symbol in the imported font, but it could be any other delimiter.

The symbols are approximations of one, two, or three english letters. Any help in this direction is appreciated!

Comment: Font mapping seems the way to go. Should *all* `ngh` groups point to the same character in the font?

Comment: @egreg Not sure what you mean by "groups". I have distinct characters "ngh", "nh", "nn", "n" and "h" that have similar English expressions. And there are no capital letters, just lowercase and punctuation.

Comment: For instance, can you have `nn` that represents the double character for `n` or does any `nn` combination represent a single character?

Comment: you can define ngh as a ligature if it is an OpenType fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should never use `\font` directly in LaTeX (or XeLaTeX, which differs just by what engine is used). The `fontspec` interface is much better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\myfont}[Mapping=jimbo,Scale=1.2]{Junicode}

\begin{document}

{\myfont abcnghd}

{\myfont abc/nn/d}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result (I used Junicode instead of your runic font).

[image]

You'll notice that `abcnghd` in the first line has become "abcZd" and `abc/nn/d` in the second "abcYd". How did I do it?

I prepared a `jimbo.map` file by copying the standard `tex-text.map` file that you can surely find in your TeX distribution and modifying it to read

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; ADDITIONS FOR JimboBimbo start here    
; ligatures for the runic font

U+006E U+0067 U+0068        <> U+005A ; ngh -> Z
U+002F U+006E U+006E U+002F <> U+0059 ; /nn/ -> Y
```

It should be clear that this mapping transforms every `ngh` cluster into a `Z` and every `/nn/` cluster into `Y`. The font is loaded with the `Mapping=jimbo` specification, so this will be done only for that font.

The mapping file should be compiled with the `teckit_compile` utility:

```
teckit_compile jimbo.map
```

will produce a `jimbo.tec` file that you should keep in the working directory (or any other in the XeTeX search tree).

What input form should you prefer? It depends on you. If *every* `ngh` cluster should be transformed into `Z`, just use the first form, which is easier to input. Otherwise, choose a non used character (here I chose `/`) for grouping clusters.

Comment: Very nice, this worked perfectly for me. Instead of the `Scale` option of `\newfontface`, I used `SizeFeatures={Size=10}`, which makes it easier for me to integrate this font with English text, the size of which is specified in `pt`, which seems also to be what the `10` refers to in size. And I used `/` to group clusters as you suggested, because there are separate letters "n", "g" and "h" that might appear together. Thanks!