# XeTeX: How to *globally* replace an ASCII character with another symbol?

Tags: xetex, characters, catcodes, ebgaramond, ascii

A few months ago, I asked [whether the “EB Garamond” font contains a short-arched version of the letter `f`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/501716). I have now found out how to access this letter because it actually exists. Writing

```
\newcommand\fshort{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "f.short" \relax}
```

makes it possible to access this letter by writing `\fshort`.

Writing

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myreplace}{m}
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l__maxd_argument_tl { #1 }
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__maxd_argument_tl { f } { \fshort }
    \tl_use:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
}
\tl_new:N \l__maxd_argument_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

will result in the replacement of `f` with the short-arched version of it when the text is encompassed by `\myreplace{}`.

This, however, is not very convenient. I would like to **globally** replace every `f` character with the short-arched `f`.

I already tried using catcodes, but they do not work when it comes to (certain) ASCII characters. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319649) which contains Cyrillic characters works perfectly fine:

```
\catcode`\Ё=\active
\defЁ{E}
\catcode`\ё=\active
\defё{e}
```

But writing something like

```
\catcode`\f=\active
\deff{\fshort}
```

or

```
\catcode`\f=\active
\def f{\fshort}
```

does not work. Also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195726) did not solve my problem.

---

David Carlisle’s solution works!

If you also want to use `Q.short` in combination with `f.short`, use the following code which has to be written in that order:

```
\newcommand\fshortgobble[1]{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "f.short" \relax}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\fclass
\XeTeXcharclass `f =\fclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \fclass  {\fshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \fclass \fclass  {\fshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \fclass  {\fshortgobble}

\newcommand\Qshortgobble[1]{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "Q.short" \relax}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\Qclass
\XeTeXcharclass `Q =\Qclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \Qclass  {\Qshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \Qclass \Qclass  {\Qshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \Qclass  {\Qshortgobble}
```

Comment: If the font has not a suitable feature, you need a TECkit mapping. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95418/2388

Comment: `f.short` does not seem to be mapped properly in the [current EB Garamond version](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/tree/master/fonts/). Therefore, I do not know the hex number for `f.short`. But accessing it with `\newcommand\fshort{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "f.short" \relax}` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a character class

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\fshortgobble[1]{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "f.short" \relax}

\newXeTeXintercharclass\fclass
\XeTeXcharclass `f =\fclass
\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \fclass  {\fshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \fclass \fclass  {\fshortgobble}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \fclass  {\fshortgobble}
\begin{document}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

f   ff  difficult football diff biff fence

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1

f   ff  difficult football diff biff fence



\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you very much. But I do not know for what `0` and `4095` stand for. Do I have to use other numbers when I am also using `Q.short` as shown in the example I just posted?

Comment: @Nemgathos see the xetex manual (texdoc xetex)  0 is the default class (so most letters) and 4095 is the non-letter class (so start of string for example)